# The invoice can't be saved at this time. Please try again later

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have 2 problems with orders:

1st, I can't change my orders status:

[image]

2nd, I can't generate invoice from my orders:

[image]

Comment: Did you look in the logs to see an error message ? In var/log/system.log

Comment: @Fbr I looked and I see no error who could solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will be useful for someone.

In my case when I got the above error I figured out I just tried to buy a gift card with empty giftcards pool.
From what I understand there can be a lot of reasons for the error and exceptions.log doesn't help to find the exact one.
If the above doesn't help I'd try debugging from:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Save.php:229
```

and would look into the backtrace.